# Collect event logs remotelly

Tags: windows, wmi, event-log

In your opinion, which is the best approach to collect the event logs remotely from several Windows machines in a network?

I need to collect the log events remotely and I have several approach (WMI, EventLog class, etc.) but I don't know what is the best way.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Are you programming the remote event log access into an app? Maybe you can elaborate on that. If so, what language are you programming in, etc.

Check out [OSSEC](http://vichargrave.com/ossec-log-management-with-elasticsearch/), perhaps in concert with Logstash and ElasticSearch.

Or you could look at [Wevutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd310329.aspx), pull event log data to a management workstation then push it into a database.

There's also [PsLogList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897544.aspx) from the sysinternals guys, which you could also use to pull the event log data, then push it into a database.

Comment: As I Know, OSSEC implies to intall OSSEC agents on each computer. Now I'm using the EventLog class that comes with .NET but, it could be a better approach to get these event logs. How about WMI? Any experience?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to do so would be configure `redis`, `rabbitMQ` or `ZeroMQ` (well supported plugins) and send all your logs to a queue server from where your `logstash indexer` will pickup all the logs and processes it.

In this way all your logs will be on central server, which you can persist as well with messaging systems I mentioned above. All your existing system will be same and do not required additional package except a simple client to push to the messaging queue.

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/

Comment: hmmm, interesting then you might look for some windows alternative to rsyslog which wllows applications to send logs to a rsyslogd server. Also it would be good if you provide us with some more details of your logging mechanism so we can see if client-less mode can be implemented.